# How do I report the max RSS of a cgroup?

Tags: cgroups, namespace, profiling

I would like to monitor the peak RSS a cgroup has used since it was created.

By "peak RSS" I mean: the sum of all processes' RSS at the point in time where that sum is the greatest.

I believe `memory.max_usage_in_bytes` reports RSS+CACHE, and AFAIK there isn't a `"max_cache_in_bytes"` metric that I can use to derive a `"max_rss_in_bytes"`.

Basically: I would love the cgroup equivalent of `time -f %M`.

Does anyone know of a way?